# Session survives browser close? Should I want to prevent this?

Tags: php, session

I have a PHP app which requires log in, offers a log out option and force logs off users who have been inactive for X minutes.

But, if I log in, close my browser and re-open it, the $_SESSION variables still exists.

What's the general practise here? Should I want to prevent this and, if so, how?

Something in me just wants to treat closing the browser as logout ... on the one hand, it's a secure app (since it requires login) but a non-tech user might reasonably expect that if they close the whole browser then no one can see their private data. Otoh, if the browser crashes and the user restarts it, he might hope to pick up where he left off ...

What do others do?

Comment: +1 "any". and "any". It's a question of best-practise & should be independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP sessions work by saving a cookie to the user's browser containing the ID of the session on the server. **Therefore PHP sessions work exactly like ordinary cookies do**.

If you close your browser, cookies are persistent. The server doesn't know what instance of the browser the user is using, whether the browser has restarted, or even if the computer has restarted.

Providing a log-out button is the most usual practice here, but if for some reason you require the user to be logged out when the browser closes, you will have to implement something client-side, as **the browser doesn't send any signal to the server when it closes.**

If you are concerned about security - i.e. you are programming a highly secure application such as a payment gateway - you can follow the practice of bank websites or other payment gateways;

When the user returns to the site, they are still logged on, but when they try to perform any action that will affect the logged-in user, re-authenticate with another password screen, or ask for some memorable information.

Comment: +1 Thanks. Unfortunately, I can't rely on client side as the user may disable JS and I am deploying to a place which may even forbid JS :-(   but I thank you for helping me learn something

Comment: @Mawg the point is that you *are* relying on client side with cookies. If you want to interact with the cookies, you could send request headers with PHP, but that defeats the point in a session.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic behavior, you can observe it on many sites, including Stack Overflow :)
Your session variable is bound to a cookie in the browser. If you want the user to really be logged off when the browser closes, sets the time of the session cookie to zero.

Comment: +1 Thanks for that. I am not setting a cookie in my code, but I admit that I don't understand all the subtleties of sessions or cookies. Now I know how to obviate this behaviour - if I can decide whether I want to ...

Answer (score 2):

When you explicitly set a cookie, you can choose its expire time.  When you're using session_start() to generate a session cookie, its expiration time is determined by the session.cookie_lifetime value in php.ini.  If you set this to 0, session cookies will expire when the browser window is closed.

Comment: +1 Thanks. Espcially for taking the time to add information to an old, closed question. That will help those who might read thsi afterwards